# Invalid JWT Format when calling a registered API from Rails protected by auth0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, jwt, auth0

I'm having some trouble understanding what to do exactly to use de SDK to call an API.

What I have done:

- An API in rails, protected by Auth0. (api)
- An Angular app, protected by Auth0. Login works.  (app1)
- Successfully called the API from the angular app.
- A new Rails web App, protected by Auth0. Login works.  (app2)
- **ERROR** calling the API from app2.

```
# Error in the logs of the api side. 
JSON::JWT::InvalidFormat Invalid JWT Format.
JWT should include 3 or 5 segments gem jwt.rb
```

I use the following code to request the API from rails using faraday:

```rb
      def request(method, path, body = {})
        conn = Faraday.new(url: @base_uri) do |c|
        c.request :url_encoded
        c.adapter :net_http
      end

      conn.send(method) do |req|
        req.url path
        req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        req.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        req.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{@token}" # 
        req.body = body.to_json
      end
```

The `@token` I use there is obtained during login in app2, in a similar way I do in app1. In this case I save it in the `callback` of the auth0 controller:

```rb
    auth_info = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    session[:userinfo] = auth_info['extra']['raw_info']
    session[:token] = auth_info['credentials']['token'] #
```

I check on docs but I always end up in the description of calling the API from Rails directly with `net/http` instead of using the SDK.

- **SDK Library used:** `omniauth-auth0` v2.5.0
- **Platform Version:** e.g. ruby 3 / rails 6.1.3.1

I need help to see what I really should call the API and/or how to fix the error.

Comment: One, and this may not affect you _yet_, but I just ran into an issue using `request` as a method name. I was getting conflict with the `controller.request` that gets called within the stack. I would suggest changing it to something else, I changed mine to `requester`. When I ran into invalid format, it was because something in the body requesting the access token was incorrect. Also do you have m2m token setup? We are able to login to our own app like you do, but when talking to a different app, we need to get the token from that app via machine to machine token.

Comment: Thanks @intl-man-of-coding-mystery, I'll try both (changing request sound logic, and m2m worth to try). I'll confirm later.